# How do I take image file as an argument in MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, input

I tried to create a MATLAB function that will take .png file as an argument, but I keep getting errors.

Here is the function:

```
    function [] = maskareddot(filename)
    red_dot=filename;
    figure, imshow(red_dot)
    boja =impixel;
    tol =10;
    mask_reddot =(red_dot(:,:,1)<boja(1)+tol) & (red_dot(:,:,1)>boja(1)-tol) & ...
         (red_dot(:,:,2)<boja(2)+tol) & (red_dot(:,:,2)>boja(2)-tol) & ...
         (red_dot(:,:,3)<boja(3)+tol) & (red_dot(:,:,3)>boja(3)-tol); 
    se=strel('disk',2);
    mask_reddot_dilate=imdilate(mask_reddot,se);
    end
```

When I write:

```
    a=imread('a.png');
    maskareddot(a);'
```

I get this error:

```
    Undefined function 'maskareddot' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're loading the image outside of the function so the input to the function isn't the `filename`, but rather the image itself.

Second of all, you must save the `maskareddot` function in a file called `maskareddot.m` and place it either in the current folder or the MATLAB path.

Comment: Thank you. I had saved the function under the wrong name